Center table headers over certain columns
I have a table, like the one below. In it, I want to center the headers A and B over the columns 2020, 2022, 2022, and 2020 - 2022 within their respective areas. How can I do that? I have tried \multicolumn, but seem to be unable to center them over their respective columns (2-5 and 6-9).

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
    \section{Intro}
    \label{sec:Intro}
    \lipsum[66]

      \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{threeparttable}
        \centering
          \begin{tabular}{l cccc | cccc}
          \toprule
          \multicolumn{3}{c}{A: Short text} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{B: A rather long text here} \\\cmidrule(r){2-5}\cmidrule(l){6-9}
          Country & 2020 & 2021 & 2022 & 2020 - 2022 & 2020 & 2021 & 2022 & 2020 - 2022 \\
          \midrule
          France  & -3.5 \% & -1.2 \% & 1.0 \% & -0.5 \% & 12.5 \% & 9.8 \% & 14.2 \% & 11.0 \%\\
          Germany & -7.2 \% & -4.6 \% & -1.1 \% & -3.8 \% & 11.7 \% & 8.3 \% & 13.5 \% & 10.1 \%\\
          Italy   & -5.8 \% & -3.0 \% & 0.5 \% & -1.9 \% & 14.0 \% & 7.6 \% & 12.8 \% & 9.5 \%\\
          Spain   & -4.1 \% & -2.7 \% & 0.8 \% & -1.2 \% & 13.2 \% & 6.9 \% & 11.5 \% & 10.7 \%\\
          Netherlands & -3.0 \% & -1.5 \% & 1.2 \% & -0.9 \% & 15.4 \% & 8.0 \% & 13.0 \% & 11.2 \%\\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


For centering content across columns 2-5 you'll need a 4-column \multicolumn and only start that multi-column in the second column (so precede it with & to skip the first column). A similar approach holds for a \multicolumn across columns 6-9.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ l *{4}{S[table-format=2.1\%]} *{4}{S[table-format=2.1\%]} }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A: Short text} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{B: A rather long text here} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-5}\cmidrule(l){6-9}
    Country     & {2020} & {2021} & {2022} & {2020--2022} & {2020} & {2021} & {2022} & {2020--2022} \\
    \midrule
    France      & -3.5\% & -1.2\% &  1.0\% &    -0.5\%    & 12.5\% &  9.8\% & 14.2\% &    11.0\%    \\
    Germany     & -7.2\% & -4.6\% & -1.1\% &    -3.8\%    & 11.7\% &  8.3\% & 13.5\% &    10.1\%    \\
    Italy       & -5.8\% & -3.0\% &  0.5\% &    -1.9\%    & 14.0\% &  7.6\% & 12.8\% &     9.5\%    \\
    Spain       & -4.1\% & -2.7\% &  0.8\% &    -1.2\%    & 13.2\% &  6.9\% & 11.5\% &    10.7\%    \\
    Netherlands & -3.0\% & -1.5\% &  1.2\% &    -0.9\%    & 15.4\% &  8.0\% & 13.0\% &    11.2\%    \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

As you can see I've added the use of siunitx to format the columns correctly. Bracing for the column year titles is needed to avoid them also being processed the new S-column.
You can reduce the column spacing to make the table fit, or decide on a different layout. Options available are discussed in My table doesn't fit; what are my options?

Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

But I am missing my vertical line in the table between the two secionts.

@KGB91 You shouldn't use vertical lines if you use the booktabs package.

@KGB91: This is one of the big things booktabs talks about avoiding in the documentation: "...never, ever use vertical lines." The idea is that the columnar layout of a table already suggests some structure that doesn't require additional, visible dividers.

A solution with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix with the advantage that, if you want to add more space between the columns 1 and 2 (and 6 and 7) with the structure @{...}, the elements centered by the command \Block (provided by {NiceTabular}) will be correctly centered (according to the contents of the corresponding columns).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{ @{}l@{\qquad} *{4}{S[table-format=2.1\%]}@{\qquad} *{4}{S[table-format=2.1\%]}@{}}
    \toprule
    & \Block{1-4}{A: Short text} &&&& \Block{1-4}{B: A rather long text here} \\
    Country     & {2020} & {2021} & {2022} & {2020--2022} & {2020} & {2021} & {2022} & {2020--2022} \\
    \midrule
    France      & -3.5\% & -1.2\% &  1.0\% &    -0.5\%    & 12.5\% &  9.8\% & 14.2\% &    11.0\%    \\
    Germany     & -7.2\% & -4.6\% & -1.1\% &    -3.8\%    & 11.7\% &  8.3\% & 13.5\% &    10.1\%    \\
    Italy       & -5.8\% & -3.0\% &  0.5\% &    -1.9\%    & 14.0\% &  7.6\% & 12.8\% &     9.5\%    \\
    Spain       & -4.1\% & -2.7\% &  0.8\% &    -1.2\%    & 13.2\% &  6.9\% & 11.5\% &    10.7\%    \\
    Netherlands & -3.0\% & -1.5\% &  1.2\% &    -0.9\%    & 15.4\% &  8.0\% & 13.0\% &    11.2\%    \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}



In order to give the table more space, first I would remove percentage unit from all values and add an annotation. I would also format the header 2020-2022 in two lines. The easiest way to do so is to load makecell package and use either \makecell{} or thead{}. Another advantage of makecell is to control vertical spacing around cells, which do not add spacing around rules defined booktabs. All this should make the table fit within the page.
I would also make the first column fixed and set remaining column to X-type. This way all columns are going to have the same size (require tabularx package.) multicol package defines a macro to merge cells vertically, which I demonstrate in my codes.
Finally, I would avoid vertical bars. In order to keep lines joined, I have done a few extra things, that is set spacing around rules to 0pt but added manual spacing (using struts) or via makecell package (using Gapes).
Here's example with vertical bar:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}\label{sec:Intro}
\section{Intro}

\lipsum[66]
\begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    % \small
    \setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
    \setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[3pt][3pt]}
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{2.25cm} *4{X} | *4{X} @{}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2.5}*{\thead{Country}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{A: Short text}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{B: A rather long text here}} \\
        % \cmidrule(r){2-5}\cmidrule(l){6-9}
        \cmidrule{2-9}
        & \thead{2020} & \thead{2021} & \thead{2022} & \thead[c]{2020-\\2022}
        & \thead{2020} & \thead{2021} & \thead{2022} & \thead[c]{2020-\\2022} \\
        \midrule
         France      & -3.5  & -1.2  & 1.0  & -0.5 & 12.5 & 9.8 & 14.2 & 11.0 \rule{0pt}{12pt}\\
         Germany     & -7.2  & -4.6  & -1.1 & -3.8 & 11.7 & 8.3 & 13.5 & 10.1 \\
         Italy       & -5.8  & -3.0  & 0.5  & -1.9 & 14.0 & 7.6 & 12.8 & 9.5 \\
         Spain       & -4.1  & -2.7  & 0.8  & -1.2 & 13.2 & 6.9 & 11.5 & 10.7 \\
         Netherlands & -3.0  & -1.5  & 1.2  & -0.9 & 15.4 & 8.0 & 13.0 & 11.2 \rule[-6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}\vspace{3pt}
        {\footnotesize All values in percentage (\%)}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Here's the same table without vertical bar. A bit simplified code.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}\label{sec:Intro}
\section{Intro}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[0pt][0pt]}
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{2.25cm} *4{X} @{\quad} *4{X} @{}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2.5}*{\thead{Country}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{A: Short text}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{B: A rather long text here}} \\
        \cmidrule(lr{11pt}){2-5}\cmidrule(l{3pt}){6-9}
        & \thead{2020} & \thead{2021} & \thead{2022} & \thead[c]{2020-\\2022}
        & \thead{2020} & \thead{2021} & \thead{2022} & \thead[c]{2020-\\2022} \\
        \midrule
         France      & -3.5  & -1.2  & 1.0  & -0.5 & 12.5 & 9.8 & 14.2 & 11.0 \\
         Germany     & -7.2  & -4.6  & -1.1 & -3.8 & 11.7 & 8.3 & 13.5 & 10.1 \\
         Italy       & -5.8  & -3.0  & 0.5  & -1.9 & 14.0 & 7.6 & 12.8 & 9.5 \\
         Spain       & -4.1  & -2.7  & 0.8  & -1.2 & 13.2 & 6.9 & 11.5 & 10.7 \\
         Netherlands & -3.0  & -1.5  & 1.2  & -0.9 & 15.4 & 8.0 & 13.0 & 11.2 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}\vspace{3pt}
        {\footnotesize All values in percentage (\%)}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}



EDIT.This edit is about maintaining a good format. Therefore, here's one more example of your table. siunitx package is a very helpful because it keeps content in the correct format as well as align numbers by a marker. Some packages are no longer required, however I added array, siunitx and caption as I also added a caption to the table.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % Dummy text


\begin{document}\label{sec:Intro}
\section{Intro}
\kant[1][1]

\begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[0pt][0pt]}
    \captionsetup{position=top, skip=3pt}
    \caption{Here is Caption of the table}
    \label{tab:example-caption}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{
            l
            *4{S[table-format=-1.1]}
            S[table-format=2.1]
            S[table-format=1.1]
            *2{S[table-format=2.1]}
        }
        \toprule
        \multirow{2.5}*{\thead{Country}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{A: Short text}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{B: A rather long text here}} \\
        \cmidrule(r){2-5}\cmidrule(l){6-9}
        & {\thead{2020}} & {\thead{2021}} & {\thead{2022}} & {\thead[c]{2020-\\2022}}
        & {\thead{2020}} & {\thead{2021}} & {\thead{2022}} & {\thead[c]{2020-\\2022}} \\
        \midrule
         France      & -3.5  & -1.2  & 1.0  & -0.5 & 12.5 & 9.8 & 14.2 & 11.0 \\
         Germany     & -7.2  & -4.6  & -1.1 & -3.8 & 11.7 & 8.3 & 13.5 & 10.1 \\
         Italy       & -5.8  & -3.0  & 0.5  & -1.9 & 14.0 & 7.6 & 12.8 & 9.5 \\
         Spain       & -4.1  & -2.7  & 0.8  & -1.2 & 13.2 & 6.9 & 11.5 & 10.7 \\
         Netherlands & -3.0  & -1.5  & 1.2  & -0.9 & 15.4 & 8.0 & 13.0 & 11.2 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        {\footnotesize All values in percentage (\%)}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\kant[1][2]
\end{document}



Thanks, that is indeed a nice alternative! Trying to learn how to make nice tables in LaTeX.

You should also make all the minus' into actual minus' and not hyphens as here.

I didn't think it would be important but it's a good point to propagate good practice. Cheers!

Another possibilities wit use tblr of tabularray package with tblr libraries booktabs and siunitx (which adopt these packages for use in tabularray tables):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
  \begin{tblr}{colsep  = {2pt},
               colspec = {@{} l *{4}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.1{\%}}]}@{\quad}
                                *{4}{X[c, si={table-format= 2.1{\%}}]}@{}},
               cell{3-Z}{2-Z} = {appto=\,\%},
               cell{1}{1}     = {r=2}{c},
               cell{1}{2, 6}  = {c=4}{c},
               row{1,2} = {c, guard}
               }
    \toprule
Country     & A: Short text &   &   &   & B: A rather long text here    &   &   &           \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-5}
    \cmidrule[l]{6-9}
            & 2020  & 2021  & 2022  & 2020--22  & 2020  & 2021  & 2022  & 2020--22      \\
    \midrule
France      & -3.5  & -1.2  &  1.0  & -0.5      & 12.5  &  9.8  & 14.2  & 11.0          \\
Germany     & -7.2  & -4.6  & -1.1  & -3.8      & 11.7  &  8.3  & 13.5  & 10.1          \\
Italy       & -5.8  & -3.0  &  0.5  & -1.9      & 14.0  &  7.6  & 12.8  &  9.5          \\
Spain       & -4.1  & -2.7  &  0.8  & -1.2      & 13.2  &  6.9  & 11.5  & 10.7          \\
Netherlands & -3.0  & -1.5  &  1.2  & -0.9      & 15.4  &  8.0  & 13.0  & 11.2          \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}



That one looks nice too! Thanks
